# TextBox validation through Methods

Tags: c#

I'm creating a class only for methods, so I can use them all the time in my project. For the moment I'm trying to make a method for textbox validation, but I'm having some problems.

I'm using this:

```
public bool ValidateIntTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBox)
{
    int value = 0;

    return int.TryParse(textBox.ToString(), out value);
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
public bool IsValid()
{
    return ValidateIntTextBoxes(AgeTextBox);
}

private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This if statement is just to test the mothod
    if(IsValid())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }

    else
    {
        AgeTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

}
```

The problem is, the IsValid() method, always returns false. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be :

`return int.TryParse(textBox[0].Text.Trim(), out value);`. Also you need to iterate over all the `textBox`es

```
public bool ValidateIntTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBox)
{
   bool valid = true;
   int value;
   foreach(var t in textBox){
     if((int.TryParse(t.Text.Trim(), out value) == false) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly as I wanted. Thank you so much for your time. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're inputting a collection of `TextBox`s, but not iterating them.  Also, you're calling `ToString` on it.

Update your `ValidateIntTextBoxes` like so:

```
public bool ValidateIntTextBoxes(TextBox textBox)
{
    int value = 0;

    return int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value);
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works perfectly! Thank you :). But what if I want to validate more than one textbox at a time ? What should I do then ?

Comment: The other answerers to your question seem to have anticipated this question - check out their answers (though probably wait a minute or two - they're furiously editing :) ).

Answer (score 0):

To validate all textboxes

```
public bool ValidateIntTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBox)
{
    return textBox.All(t => { 
                              int value = 0; 
                              return int.TryParse(t.Text, out value); 
                            });
}
```

Comment: It's still returning false all the time.